# Generate Excel files for each of element in a column using Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to generate Excel files for each of element in a column :
I will describe what I want with pictures :

I have an excel file like this:

[image]

I want for each element of the column "FRUIT", to be on a different excel file like this :

excel-BANANA.xlsx :

[image]

excel-CHERRY.xlsx :

[image]

excel-APPLE.xlsx :

[image]

Is it possible ?

Comment: The `csv` module provides simple tools to do this sort of thing with `.csv` files. You might also look at `pandas` which is much higher-level and more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *BoarGules* mentioned, you can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Removes the default header style so it looks like your screenshots
pd.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

df = pd.read_excel(r"fruits.xlsx")

for fruit in df['FRUIT'].unique():
    df.loc[df['FRUIT'] == fruit].to_excel(f"excel-{fruit}.xlsx", index=False)
```

It reads the `fruits.xlsx`, iterates over the unique values in the `FRUIT` column (in this case: BANANA, CHERRY, and APPLE), and filters the dataframe to include only that one fruit each iteration.

`to_excel(f"excel-{fruit}.xlsx", index=False)` saves the dataframe as an Excel file without including an index (row numbers).

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals